# XMLRPC error in jenkins while using testlink

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, testlink

Error while communicating to test-link through Jenkins test-link plugin.

```
14:43:17 Using TestLink URL: http://<hostname>/testlink-code-testlink_1_9/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php
14:43:17 
14:43:17 FATAL: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Not Found
14:43:17 br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Not Found
14:43:17    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:64)
14:43:17    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI.<init>(TestLinkAPI.java:148)
14:43:17    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.getTestLinkSite(TestLinkBuilder.java:331)
14:43:17    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.perform(TestLinkBuilder.java:206)
14:43:17    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
14:43:17    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
14:43:17    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
14:43:17    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
14:43:17    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
14:43:17    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
14:43:17    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
14:43:17    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
14:43:17    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
14:43:17 Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransportException: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Not Found
14:43:17    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.getInputStream(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:94)
14:43:17    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:152)
14:43:17    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
14:43:17    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
14:43:17    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
14:43:17    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
14:43:17    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
14:43:17    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
14:43:17    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.BaseService.executeXmlRpcCall(BaseService.java:83)
14:43:17    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:61)
14:43:17    ... 12 more
14:43:17 ERROR: Error communicating with TestLink. Check your TestLink configuration.
14:43:17 Finished: FAILURE
```

Also I have checked in the server this is the path is used. Not sure why still unable to communicate with the test-link.

basically I am trying to run the test from Jenkins GitHub code and updating my test execution in test-link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys it got fixed by asking the devops to enable the XMLRPC path from nginix side.

So basically what happens when we try to access files for which path is not defined and it says file not found when you hit from browser.

So basically you need to enabled the path and check you are accessing the right path to access the XMLRPC